Given $M, N$, how to find matrix $M'$ such that $M'N = NM$
Consider an arbitrary $p\times q$ matrix $N$, an arbitrary $q\times q$ matrix $M$.
I do not know if $N$ is invertible - the solution is easy when it is. Is there a way to always find a $p\times p$ $M'$ such that it satisfies
$$M' N = N M$$
and is the $M'$ unique?

@Surb but $NM$ is $(p\times q)\cdot(q\times q)$ which is $p\times q$, isn't it?

Someone please correct me if wrong, but essentially we're trying to solve for the $p^2$ unknown elements of $M'$ with $pq$ equations. I imagine if $p<q$ then in general there'll be no solutions, and if $p>q$ there might be infinite solutions. Not too sure yet about $p=q$ and $N$ is non-invertible, will need a think. Oh, and in general if there is a solution for $M'$ then it might not be unique if you can add on a non-zero matrix $V$ with row vectors from $N$'s left-nullspace, meaning $(M'+V)N=NM$.

@user1936752: indeed, you are right, I was mistaken.
